# How do I access variables dynamically with go templating?

Tags: go, hugo

I'm using hugo as a static site generator, and need to do something like this:

$.Site.Data.pages[{{ .Params.location }}].someStuff

I am not sure of the syntax to actually accomplish this and it's such an irritatingly simple thing that it's actually difficult to find by googling

Comment: [hugo: access custom data](https://gohugo.io/extras/datafiles) - this may help.

Comment: Can you clarify please what do you want to achieve exactly? The code line doesn't say much. Do you want to access custom variable from the front matter of .md, or from config, or custom data?